# How to change the cursor type and color?

Tags: cursor, customize

I would like to change the cursor, like in Terminal, from the block to the I-Beam cursor.

From this:

[image: Block]

To this:

[image: Ibeam]

How would I do this?

Also, on a side note, how do I change the color of the cursor?

Answer (score 60, accepted):

In order to change your cursor or caret, what you want to do is:

Open your .emacs file and this line of code:

```
(setq-default cursor-type 'bar)
```

And to change the color:

```
(set-cursor-color "#ffffff")
```

Of course, you can change `#ffffff` to any hexadecimal  color.

Comment: Just saw a lot of pretty colors at kuler but I think your answer is better without the reference.

Answer (score 16):

Cursor type can be set for a given **buffer** (using buffer-local variable `cursor-type`), as indicated in the answer by @King. (That answer uses `setq-default` to set the default value for all buffers.)

Or it can be set for a given **frame**, as frame parameter `cursor-type`.

You can set it the default cursor type for all frames by adding it to option `default-frame-alist`. For example add this item to the alist: `(cursor-type . bar)`.

Here is a command (from library [oneonone.el](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/oneonone.el) to set the cursor type for the current frame:

```
(defun 1on1-set-cursor-type (cursor-type)
  "Set the cursor type of the selected frame to CURSOR-TYPE.
When called interactively, prompt for the type to use.
To get the frame's current cursor type, use `frame-parameters'."
  (interactive
   (list (intern (completing-read
                   "Cursor type: "
                   (mapcar 'list '("box" "hollow" "bar" "hbar" nil))))))
  (modify-frame-parameters (selected-frame) (list (cons 'cursor-type cursor-type))))
```

Cursor *color* is always per-*frame*, not per-buffer.

(In library `oneonone.el` you will also find options to automatically change the cursor type when you switch a buffer between read-only and writable, or between overwrite mode and insert mode, or to change the type to a box cursor (more noticeable) when Emacs is idle.)

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately I can't comment yet, but I also tried to change the color by adding the command `(set-cursor-color "#ffff00")`. When I reload my emacs, I don't get it to work though. The cursor is still white (not as expected: yellow). I used the `M-x eval-buffer` and for a fraction of a second my cursor got yellow and returned to white shortly afterwards. What is the problem there?

**EDIT:**
I use evil-mode and because they handle it differently, you can copy this and customize it in a way you want. I copied this from the website @g-gundam provided.

```
(setq          evil-default-cursor       '("DodgerBlue1" box)
              evil-normal-state-cursor  '("gray" box)
              evil-emacs-state-cursor   '("orange" box)
              evil-motion-state-cursor  '("SeaGreen1" box)
              evil-insert-state-cursor  '("white" bar)
              evil-visual-state-cursor  '("white" hbar)
              evil-replace-state-cursor '("pink" hbar))
```

Comment: Are you using evil-mode by any chance?  It has its own cursor color control.  https://old.reddit.com/r/emacs/comments/71czre/how_to_customize_cursor_color_in_solarized/

Comment: Yes I use emacs-evil. This worked as well for me. Thanks for helping me out... (again) :^)

Comment: You could add value to your answer by describing the solution provided by @g-gundam.

Comment: @FranBurstall Sure! I edited my response :)