# Howto to change color of cursor and highlighted window in spacemacs

Tags: spacemacs, themes

In particular, I have a blue cursor (and highlighted window), which seems to correspond with spacemacs' [Emacs mode](http://boyanangelov.com/spacemacs/doc/DOCUMENTATION.html#orgheadline50).

But I'd like to put that color to yellow or something else. Don't see that in the ["Color themes" section](http://boyanangelov.com/spacemacs/doc/DOCUMENTATION.html#orgheadline64) of Spacemacs' guide. And I don't seem to have a `cursor-color` variable, as [described here](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/392/how-to-change-the-cursor-type-and-color).

How can we tweak the cursor and highlighted window color, without changing modes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using Spacemacs with Emacs editing style, you first have to set `dotspacemacs-colorize-cursor-according-to-state nil` in your `dotspacemacs/init (setq-default ...`.  This enables you to configure the cursor color from whatever theme you are using without Spacemacs automatically overwriting it.

To customize spacemacs colors you can type `M-x` `customize-group` `spacemacs`.
To change the color of the cursor I refer you to [this SO thread here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4642835/how-to-change-the-cursor-color-on-emacs).

Comment: Ah, ok cool. What's the spacemacs function to then set the cursor and highlighted window color?

Comment: @Nutritioustim just added to answer.

Comment: you are a life saver :)) thank you, this worked for me.